# iPhone clear UIView alpha at touch location

Tags: iphone, ios, transparent, alpha, quartz-core

I want to present an image in a `UIView`, because I have to customize `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`. I have to clear the view's alpha where the user "rubs" the screen, so the subview behind this view will become visible.
If I use a solid color it works fine, but when I try to draw an image and clear the view just where the user touched the screen, the image is not drawn. 
Can you help me, how should I draw the `UIImage`, to be drawn in the background and to become transparent in a particular *rect*, please?

This is my code which works with solid color (as it is now):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor );
    CGContextFillRect( context, rect );

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor );
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y, 30, 30));

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good control on github for that purpose already.
check out:

https://github.com/akopanev/iOS-Scratch-n-See

I used it as a starting point for a "scratch game" app already.
The delegate receives also the information how much of the screen/image is already cleared (i.e. "scratched away").

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem... but if the problem is that the drawRect is not called when the user touch the screen... try this:

put a

```
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

in your touch event... a UIGestureRecognizer or overriding the UITouches methods

Comment: no, drawrect is called, but if I try to put a code like this: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"];
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0,320, 480), image.CGImage); to have a background image instead of the green color, the image is not visible..

Comment: There is notig wrong in your code, have you checked the image object if is != nil ? Second... don't use the file extension for png assets use it like [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu"] the system will load the correct assets @2x or regular from the bundle (this is TRUE only for .png files)